# how to make query in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, join

SELECT facilities.facility_name,

CASE
WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-1')
THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-1' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_1,
CASE
WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-2')
THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-2' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_2 ,
CASE
WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-3')
THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-3' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_3,
CASE
WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-4')
THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-4' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_4,
COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name) AS ANC_total
FROM compliance_visits

INNER JOIN facilities  ON compliance_visits.facility_id  = facilities.facility_id
INNER JOIN compliances_master ON compliance_visits.compliance_id = compliances_master.compliance_id
GROUP BY (facilities.facility_name)

Comment: Did below query works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this and let me know if it's working or not.

```
\DB::('compliance_visits')->select('facilities.facility_name')
->addSelect(\DB::raw("CASE WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-1') THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-1' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_1, CASE WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-2') THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-2' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_2 , CASE WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-3') THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-3' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_3, CASE WHEN (compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-4') THEN COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name = 'Antenatal Care-4' ) ELSE '0' END AS ANS_4, COUNT(compliances_master.compliance_phase_name) AS ANC_total"))
->join('facilities','facilities.facility_id','compliance_visits.facility_id')
->join('compliances_master','compliances_master.compliance_id','compliance_visits.compliance_id')
->groupBy('facilities.facility_name');
```